# attaching excel file (XLSX) in email

Tags: python, excel, python-3.x, gmail

I'm trying to attach an XLSX file in an email. I'm able to send the XLSX file and view it using google's internal excel, but when I download the file it doesn't save as an XLSX file.

Here is a snippet of the part where I attach the XLSX file:

```
path = os.listdir('C:\\Users\\Myuser\\Desktop\\Excelfiles') 
output = [i for i in path][-1]
filename = 'C:\\Users\\MyUser\\Desktop\\Excelfiles\\{0}'.format(output)
content_type,encoding = mimetypes.guess_type(filename)
main_type, sub_type = content_type.split('/', 1)
fp = open(filename,'rb')
att = MIMEApplication(fp.read(), sub_type)
fp.close()
att.add_header('Content-Disposition','attachment',filename="Test")
msg.attach(att)
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing this line:

```
att.add_header('Content-Disposition','attachment',filename="Test")
```

To:

```
att.add_header('Content-Disposition','attachment',filename="Test.xlsx")
```

Since you need to add `.xlsx` to the end of the filename.

Comment: @dko512 Edited please check :-)